# CCP PWM Strange behavior - Brief failing

Tags: microcontroller, pic, pwm, c

I am trying generate a PWM using CCP and change its frequency on the fly, going from 1.15KHz to 3.28kHz in 180ms.

I am using:

**PIC**: 16F887

**Frequency**: 4MHz (internal)

**Compiler**: CCS PCM C Compiler, Version 5.008

**My problem is**: My code is generating the PWM and going from 1.15KHz to 3.28kHz (50% duty) in 180ms as I wish to active, but it is also generating "holes", gaps, where nothing happens for some time.

This gaps goes from 3,7ms to 4,07ms, as shown by this image I could get from my oscilloscope: 
[image: My wave]

I am doing this using the following code:

**main.h**

```
#include <16F887.h> 
#device adc=8 

#FUSES NOWDT                    //No Watch Dog Timer 
#FUSES HS                       //High speed Osc (> 4mhz for PCM/PCH) (>10mhz for PCD) 
#FUSES NOPUT                    //No Power Up Timer 
#FUSES NOMCLR                   //Master Clear pin used for I/O 
#FUSES NOPROTECT                //Code not protected from reading 
#FUSES NOCPD                    //No EE protection 
#FUSES NOBROWNOUT               //No brownout reset 
#FUSES IESO                     //Internal External Switch Over mode enabled 
#FUSES FCMEN                    //Fail-safe clock monitor enabled 
#FUSES NOLVP                    //No low voltage prgming, B3(PIC16) or B5(PIC18) used for I/O 
#FUSES NODEBUG                  //No Debug mode for ICD 
#FUSES NOWRT                    //Program memory not write protected 
#FUSES BORV40                   //Brownout reset at 4.0V 
#FUSES RESERVED                 //Used to set the reserved FUSE bits 

#use delay(clock=4000000)
```

**main.c**

```
/* 
   Effect vars 
*/ 
short STATE = 1; 
int PR_VALUE = 33; 
short CHANGED = 0; 
int16 counter = 0; 

#int_RDA 
void  RDA_isr(void) 
{ 
   //TO-DO    
} 


/* 
   Runs every 256us 
*/ 
#int_RTCC 
void  RTCC_isr(void) 
{ 
   counter++; 
} 

/* 
   Performs a step every 20x256us = 5.12ms 
   Goes from 53 (1.15KHz) to 18 (3.28Khz) 
*/ 
void EFFECT(){ 
   if(counter >= 20){ 
      CHANGED = 1; 
      if(STATE){ 
         PR_VALUE++; 
         if(PR_VALUE >= 53) STATE = 0; 
      }else{ 
         PR_VALUE--; 
         if(PR_VALUE <= 18) STATE = 1; 
      } 

      counter = 0; 
   } 

   if(CHANGED){ 
      CHANGED = 0; 

      setup_timer_2(T2_DIV_BY_16, PR_VALUE, 1); 
      set_pwm1_duty(PR_VALUE/2); 
      set_pwm2_duty(PR_VALUE/2); 
   } 
} 




void main() 
{ 

   setup_comparator(NC_NC_NC_NC); 
   setup_adc_ports(NO_ANALOGS|VSS_VDD); 
   setup_adc(ADC_CLOCK_DIV_2); 
   setup_spi(SPI_SS_DISABLED); 

   setup_timer_0(RTCC_INTERNAL|RTCC_DIV_1); 

   setup_timer_1(T1_DISABLED);  

   setup_oscillator(OSC_4MHZ); 

   enable_interrupts(INT_RTCC); 

   enable_interrupts(INT_RDA); 

   enable_interrupts(GLOBAL); 

   setup_ccp1(CCP_PWM_L_H); 
   setup_ccp2(CCP_PWM_H_L); 

   while(1){ 
      EFFECT();  
   } 
}
```

Things I have done trying to fix this problem:

- Removed the counter and added a push button and for every push I incremented the PR value, I went from 18 1.15KHz to 3.28Khz without this "holes" appearing
- Attached an square wave frequency generator to the input where the push button was and noticed that the fasted I changed the PR more "holes" appeared

Any ideas how I am able to remove this weird errors?

Comment: I forget whether that PIC's CCP counts up or down when generating PWM, but assuming it counts up and you change the PR from a higher number to a lower number when the count is somewhere in between, then it'll wait until it rolls over past 0xffff and back around to 0 before getting to your new PR value. If it actually counts down, then reverse the logic and the same problem occurs.

Comment: I inverted the logic and still have the same error, the "hole" still appear

Comment: The solution is to either reset the count whenever you change the PR, or only change the PR when it's 'safe' to do so (when you know that the 'new' value hasn't already passed by).

Comment: How can I reset the CPP counter? or check if it is safe to change the PR?

Comment: The CCP's PWM function uses Timer 2 as its timebase, so read Timer 2 so check its current value or write it to reset it.

Comment: To confirm, It is save to change my PR when my Timer2 is smaller than it?